# Can closure in swift be used for communication between 2 classes?

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, block

I have a custom cell for a `UITableView`. When user taps on a button in cell, user has to get navigated from the current `ViewController1` to `ViewController2`. I have defined the button action in the custom cell class. But needs a call back to the `ViewController1`.

I tried using **closure** similar to how we use blocks in objective C. It works fine while using in the same class. But getting errors while using in 2 different classes.

Comment: Post what you have tried (some code). It's possible passing closures between 2 VCs.

Comment: You need to use protocols. I will post answer soon

Comment: Yes, use delegates & protocols or notifications alternatively!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use delegate protocols there.

**Example:** Protocol for sending `UserItem` when something happened in `cell`:

```
protocol TappedUserDelegate: class {
    func userInfoTapped(_ tappedUser: UserItem?)
}
```

In your `controller`:

```
extension Controller: TappedUserDelegate {
    func userInfoTapped(_ user: UserItem?) {
        // user is tapped user in cell    
    }
}
```

In your `tableView` func:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // ........
    cell.delegateUserTaps = self // for user info taps to perform segue
    // ........
}
```

In your custom `cell`:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
   weak var delegateUserTaps: TappedUserDelegate? // for sending user info

   // ........
   func userInfoTapped() {
       delegateUserTaps?.userInfoTapped(userItem) // <- send data to controller
   }
}
```

When `userInfoTapped` will be called, your function in controller will be performed with this user.

I've given you an idea.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. I'm unable to upvote your answer as I dont have 15 reputation.